# Am I using Java assertions right?

Tags: java, assert

```
public Card getCard()throws IOException{
    Card c = null;
    String cardInfo = null;  
    assert readStream != null: cardInfo = readStream.readLine();
    assert cardInfo != null: c = CreateCard(cardInfo);
    return c;
}
```

I'm a little outta practice and I am trying to improve my code quality by using the assert statement to test for nulls.  The way it seems to work I end up having to daisy chain my assertions because if the first thing I test for is null, then the next one is gonna be a null as well....

Comment: With Java assertions, the part after the colon is the message to the reader, and it goes to standard output.  Also, if `readStream` is null, them the next part never gets executed, so you don't have to worry about `cardInfo`.  But where are you getting `readStream` from?  What is the purpose of this method?

Comment: Note that you need to launch the JVM with `-ea` for assertions to be enabled

Answer (score 1):

Here are some guidelines with regards to assertions

- Don't use assertions to validate parameters of public functions.
  These functions should throw NullPointerException,
  IllegalArgumentException, and other relevant exceptions instead.
  Since public functions will be used by other programmers, you should
  make sure that they get the right errors if they mess up.
- Use assertions to check preconditions and postconditions on
  parameters of protected and private access methods.
- Don't use assertions to check for software user errors. If you expect
  the user of your web-based online sales system to enter a 10-digit
  credit card number and she enters only 9 digits, don't use an assert.
  Instead, throw IllegalArgumentException. If you use assert, as soon
  as someone turns off assertions on your servlet container, the
  checking logic in your system would go away.
- Use assertions to check parameters and variables for conditions that
  shouldn't happen
- Use assertions to check for invalid code branches
- Don't use an assertion to do any work. Assertions are developer-level
  errors and shouldn't be used to repair state in the program or
  perform complex logging. Also, don't forget that if a user runs the
  program without assertions, the code will be gone. If that code was
  critical to the functioning of the program, you could be in deep
  trouble.
- Don't bother internationalizing assertion error messages. Again,
  since assertions are developer-level issues, internationalizing them
  would be a waste of time.
- Use assertions to check post conditions. If you create a method and
  expect that it will never to return null to the user

Answer (score 0):

The value of an assertion is that it can be ON in development and OFF in production.  While on, it reveals bugs, presumably before they do much damage, prior to a release.  While off, the assertions are inactive and (hopefully) sport a negligible performance impact.

I think the question to ask yourself is:  "Self, does my usage of assertions meet those criteria?"